# console application and SSRS report windows auth

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, console-application

I have a console app. (vb.net) that calls several SSRS reports.  This will be executed by SQL agent that's using a windows account in the services.  This account does have access to our reporting server.  The process works fine when I hardcode a username, pw, domain.
Dim cred As New ReportServerCredentials("user","pw", "domain")
but before I can move to prod. Accounts can not be hardcoded, so I need to use windows auth.  I tried using this: serverReport.ReportServerCredentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
but it's not working.
this is the error I get.
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.SystemNetworkCredential' to type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials'

How can I call an SSRS report via windows auth. only?

Comment: Not sure, but if you can't figure it out, and you just need the reports rendered you can use [URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=URL%20access%20of%20the%20report%20server%20in%20SQL,mode%20report%20server%20or%20in%20a%20SharePoint%20library) instead of the report viewer apis.

Comment: this is a scheduled job from SQL that will loop thru. a table and create pdfs,emails, and put documents in shared folders.   it works fine only if I include the credentials.  is there no way to allow windows auth?

Comment: I don't know.  Can you post a short, complete repro of what you have?

Comment: this works if I pass username/login which I don't want to do.
Dim cred As New ReportServerCredentials(_ReportServerLogin, _ReportServerPw, _ReportServerDomain)

this does not when using the current logon which has access to run the reports.
 serverReport.ReportServerCredentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials